# PDO lastInsertId returns 0

Tags: php, pdo

I keep getting 0 in PDO `lastInsertId`. Here are my codes:

```
public static function createNewUser($email){

    $password = self::rand_string(6);

    $username = explode("@", $email);

    $username = $username[0];

    $passwordhashed = password_hash($password. self::salt(), PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $register = self::connect()->prepare("INSERT INTO `user`(email,username,password,password_salt,type)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)");

    $register->execute(array($email,$username,$passwordhashed,$password,'customer'));

    $user_id = self::pdolastid();

    if($register){

        return $user_id;

    }
    else{

        return false;

    }

}
```

and the last insert id function is:

```
public static function pdolastid(){

    $last = self::connect()->lastInsertId();

    return $last;

}
```

I have tried both with the pdolastid function and with `self::connect()->lastInsertId()`.
The connect function is:

```
public static function connect(){

    $servername = "localhost";

    $username = "root";

    $password = "";

    try {

        $conn = new \PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=pw;port=3306;charset=utf8", $username, $password);

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        return $conn;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {

        $con_error = "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();

        return $con_error;

    }

}
```

The database has id as the primary key and is auto-increment

Someone please help

Comment: You're creating a new connection each time you call `connect()` ...

Comment: How should I go about it please?

Comment: Save connection into a variable `$con = self::connect(); $con->prepare(...);$con->lastInsertId();`

Comment: I would say that even this approach would be still superfluous and harmful. [Connection have to be done only once](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#dsn) during script execution!

Comment: Perfect. It worked. Had thought of that but somehow I didn't pursue it. Thanks a lot.